# when using a list, then randomizing it, how can I use an if statement to check if a certain item in the list is printed?

Tags: python

```
 import random
 x = ["cake, cheese, milk", "cereal, milk, yogurt", "chips, cheese dip, bowl"]
 print(random.choice(x) + " is your grocery list")
```

now when that happens, I want an if statement depending on what was printed, since it is random I won't know in advance, how could I do this?

if I did something wrong in the stuff above it's because I'm exhausted

Comment: Do you mean like ' if random.choice(x) == 'cake' '

Answer (score 3):

In the below code, the `printed` list keeps track of printed items.

```
import random

max1 = ["cake, cheese, milk", "cereal, milk, yogurt", "chips, cheese dip, bowl"]
printed = []

# you may want to repeat the below lines for more choices.
choice = random.choice(max1)
printed.append(choice)
print(choice + " is your grocery list") 

print(printed)
```

### Output

```
chips, cheese dip, bowl is your grocery list
['chips, cheese dip, bowl']
```

if you are not going to repeat the process. use this one:

```
import random

max1 = ["cake, cheese, milk", "cereal, milk, yogurt", "chips, cheese dip, bowl"]
printed = random.choice(max1)
print(printed + " is your grocery list") 
print(printed)
```

### Output

```
chips, cheese dip, bowl is your grocery list
cake, cheese, milk
```

**Bonus tip:** don't use the `max` keyword for a variable name. although it shows no error its name is used for the max method and when you override it you'll lose access to that method.

Comment: Wait huh? I'm confused on that

Comment: @BrandonHunt I used another list to store whatever the `random.choice` method chooses. also, you can use just a simple `str` variable. but I assumed that if you want to repeat the choosing process.

Comment: Ahh... I see. one question. Why did the list variable have to change into another variable? Sorry If this question is dumb, I'm starting new and I just can't grasp new concepts that well

Comment: @BrandonHunt do you mean the name of the list? because actually, `max` is one of the built-in functions. if you use `max` name for your list then you are not able to use the `max` function anymore.

Comment: no, I mean the variable for the list. I figured max was a function

Comment: @BrandonHunt if you want to print only one output (which your code does now) you only need one variable to store it. so, my second code fits your question better. I mean there would be no need to use list. but in case you want to repeat the random selection process, the output would be more than just one. so I used a list in my first code to store multiple printed items. I think in your case the second is just fine.